# Python code location on debian

Tags: linux, debian, python, directory, virtualenv

Simple question, which of these is a better directory setup for locating my project and why, as I have seen both recommended on different tutorial sites:

Option 1:

```
/var/www/<projectname>/project
/var/www/<projectname>/venv
```

Option 2:

```
/home/<username>/project
/home/<username>/venv
```

Comment: It depends on your needs. Putting it under /var/www is more generic and better for sharing with others; keeping it under your own home directory would perhaps be better for your own development copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/www/` is a common place for web projects.

One option is to create a symlink from `/home/<username>/project` to `/var/www/<projectname>/project` so wherever you look, you'll find your project.